# Different data from GET request (heroku.com)

Tags: python, flask, heroku, get

I have deployed my python app with flask to heroku.com :

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_cors import CORS 
from flask import Response  
from flask import request       
import sys  
import json 

app = Flask(__name__)   
CORS(app)   


cards = [   
    {"id": "1", "header": "x", "description": "y" },    
    {"id": "2", "header": "y": "description": "z" },    
    {"id": "3", "header": "z": "description": "x" },    
    {"id": "4", "header": "y", "description": "x" } 
]   


@app.route('/cards/', methods=['GET'])  
def get_cards():    
    return json.dumps(cards)    

@app.route('/cards/', methods=['POST']) 
def post_cards():   
    new_card = json.loads(request.data) 
    max_id = 0  
    for card in cards:  
      if int(card['id']) > max_id:  
        max_id = int(card['id'])    
    new_card['id'] = str(max_id + 1)    
    cards.append(new_card)  
    return new_card

if __name__=="__main__":    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If I post new card and then try to get all card several times in a row, I always get different data (sometimes I receive initial cards set, sometimes updated cards set).
What could be the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in your global variable ‘cards’. Use some database instead